# React-native-firebase not displaying on iOS

Tags: react-native-firebase

I am making an app that calls from a firebase Firestore and displays teams for certain players. For some reason when logging in on iOS simulators, it logs in fine but won't display and teams. It does however display teams when logged in on android. If you have encountered this problem or can think of a solution please help.

Comment: you should provide more information. react-native-firebase provide functional only, it's nothing to do with `display` sth on your ui

Comment: I found the problem, the ListView being used was outdated and wouldn’t work on iOS